# ckeditor: using Google font as inline editor style?

Tags: css, fonts, ckeditor

I am using CKeditor and want the contents of the editor pane to match what appears on my site's published pages as closely as possible. This includes using a specialized Google font ('Lato:300', http://tinyurl.com/o6njmzw)

I can't find any way to get the editor to use this font though? Contents.css seems to ignore it (I don't really understand why?) Can anyone help?

(nb. I am trying to use the font as the **default font** for all text in the editor pane, **not just as an extra option in the styles drop-down**)

Thanks.

Comment: Why not include a link to your website stylesheet in your ckEditor?

Comment: Hi Coop, I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "in my ckeditor"? I have included the font-family property in the contents.css file which is where cke gets its styles from, which as I said gets ignored. The import code <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> I have included on the page above any other style sheets and before the ckeditor code.

Comment: Does contents.css still work at all; can you set something simple there like color:#c0ff33;?

Comment: Hi Neno, yes, I can set color, background-color & perhaps a few other properties... but not the font.

Comment: @Inigo When ckeditor loads, it's in an iframe, so putting the font code on the same page as it is useless. CKeditor has the functionality to link entire stylesheets through the config.js file. That way, you can make sure every style is the same, not just the font!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are setting it correctly? I just tested this and it worked for me (contents.css):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Lato Light'), local('Lato-Light'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/lato/v6/KT3KS9Aol4WfR6Vas8kNcg.woff) format('woff');
}

body
{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, "Trebuchet MS";
    font-size: 12px;
    color: red;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Also, make sure that you are not loading contents.css from cache!

Comment: OMG! It worked! For some reason I didn't even try using @font-face within contents.css, I had stuck with the stylesheet link in the head of my edit HTML page. I think the problem relates to then applying this font to the iframe in which the ckeditor content is held... conversely, contents.css is loaded along with the iFrame so that's why it works, I guess? Anyway, THANK YOU, very much appeciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution only works with browsers supporting WOFF fonts.

Answer (score 2):

Nenotlelp's solution doesn't work with browsers that don't support WOFF fonts. A better approach is to add the CSS files for the webfonts using [`config.contentsCss`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss). Example:

```
config.contentsCss = [
    CKEDITOR.getUrl('contents.css'),
    'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,700'
];
```

Comment: It might actually be better to do this this way for compatibility.